# STL List adding and removing chosen element

Tags: c++, list, stl

I'm coding simple program which uses lists. I've already created my list with all of its functions, but now I would like to convert it to STL. I've successfully done it a few of my functions but I'm stuck with a one which should add new element and also remove an element chosen by the user.

Thats my code:

```
list <Komputer> lista_komputerow_STL;
list <Komputer>::iterator it;
///This should add an element:
lista_komputerow_STL.push_back(Komputer(nazwa));
///This should remove chosen element:
int element;

for(int i=0;i<(element-1);i++)
{it++;}
lista_komputerow_STL.erase(it);
```

I am completaly new to STL and it seems to be to much for me for now, but I hope that with your help I'll get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must initialize the iterator :

```
list <Komputer>::iterator it = lista_komputerow_STL.begin();
```

Also the chosen `element` is not initialized and I suppose that your for statement should be:

```
int element = 0;
for(int i=0; i<element; i++)      // Without the '-1'
...
```

And I would suggest to use `std::advance` to shift the iterator instead of a for loop:

```
std::advance(it, element);
```

But you may look at a [base example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) and let me know if there is something you don't get...